# Selecting certain nodes with some restrictions using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

Help please:
in xml document having data about publishing papers I want to show the titles of papers which were published in 2009 only

Why this 2.0 XPath is not giving anything ? 
//title[year=2009] 
this is link to the xml file I am querying http://www.csd.uwo.ca/courses/CS4411b/paperdata.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
//inproceedings[year=2009]/title
```

Basically you first get the "paper" as you call the `inproceedings` node, and then fetch only those that have a year equal to `2009`. Then for those `inproceedings` nodes you keep the title of them.

You can test it [here](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi).

Comment: Yes I tried it and it worked.however, I did not understand how to use the online Query Tester you posted as a link. Is ther any helpful tutorial so I understand how it works. This including where to put the xml file and where to write the xpath query.

Comment: No problem. Just paste the XML code in the upper left textarea then the regular expression on the upper right text area and on the last one, select XPath 2.0 is the radio button (the second one) then the results automatically appear in the textarea below.